# how to use python to draw a gradient vector graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a gradient vector graph for the function

[image]

like this:

[image]

but the running result of my code is:

[image]

is there something wrong with my code?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define the function
def func(x, y):
    return 1/20 * x**2 + y**2

# define gradient function
def gradient(x, y):
    return np.gradient(func(x, y))

# generate the input
x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 20)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# calculate the gradient
Gx, Gy = gradient(X, Y)

# plot the gradient graph
plt.quiver(X, Y, Gx, Gy)
plt.show()
```

how I can solve the problem

Comment: Looks like plotting `plt.quiver(X, Y, -Gy, -Gx)` gives the expected result.

Comment: oh, it works, I really appreciate for your help!

Comment: Good news ! I've created a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `plt.quiver` with reversed direction vector parameter (`Gx` and `GY`) should give you the expected results :

```py
plt.quiver(X, Y, -Gy, -Gx)
```

Adding a bit of style and axis formating, here is how you'll get the expected figure

```py
# [...]

# generate the input
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 11)

# [...]
# plot the gradient graph
plt.quiver(X, Y, -Gy, -Gx, color="grey")

# format the axis
plt.grid(ls=":")
plt.xticks([-10, -5, 0, 5, 10])
plt.xlim([-10, 10])
plt.xlabel("x")

plt.ylim([-5, 5])
plt.ylabel("y")
```

[image]